What's the purpose of "also" here?
In Loving Vincent (2017), Dr. Gachet's sheltered daughter, Marguerite meets postman Joseph Roulin's son Armand in a farm:

Marguerite: If it isn't the Provence pugilist. Should I be scared?
Armand: I thought you didn't go in for village gossip.
Marguerite: I don't. That's why one employs servants. They get it for
you.
Armand: Did you also hear that your friendly local gendarme put me up
for the night?

What's the purpose of "also" here?

also is alluding to a second bit of gossip.  Its meaning might have been clearer if it were placed after hear.  But the current placement is idiomatic in conversation, though it's the kind of thing editors often fix in writing.  Two instances of hearing gossip.

Did you hear as well that ...
Did you hear, too, that ...
Did you hear, also, that ...
Did you also hear that ...


very informative and detailed thanks.

The adverb also is used here to connect what is following to an earlier utterance.
In the third line, Marguerite said her servant(s) got some news for her, possibly through some village gossip.
Armand then asked whether she also heard that her friendly local gendarme put him up for the night.  Armand treated these two items to be similar and
used also to link them together.
